# How to read words from a text file and add to an array of strings?

Tags: c, arrays

Here is my function which is called with:`getWord(words);`

```
void getWord(char words[][MAXWORDLENGTH]){
int i;
char newWord[MAXWORDLENGTH];
FILE* file;
file = fopen("wordbank.txt","r");
if(file==NULL){
    printf("Error\n");
}else{
    printf("File read\n");
    for(i=0;i<=MAXWORDS;i++){
        fgets(newWord, "%s", file);
        printf("newWord: %s", newWord);
        strcpy(words[i], newWord);
    }

}
fclose(file);
```

}

Unfortunately my array "words" does not fill each element with a string, it is able to capture the first word in my text file into the [0] element and then the rest is gibberish.

my text file looks like this:

```
apple
winter
summer
skunk
clouds
pencil
grape
```

Would it be easier for me to use a pointer instead of an array?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wrong use of `fgets()`.  `fgets(newWord, "%s", file);` --> `fgets(newWord, sizeof newWord, file);`

Comment: How many compiler warnings did you ignore with this code? Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and fix all warnings before considering your code done.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I clicked the boxes for those compiler flags and they it removed the 2 warnings, is it supposed to add more warnings since my code is wrong?

Comment: @chux That fixed the issue of gibberish printing out when I attempt to print words[i], then i++, although it prints my first word, followed by 3 blank lines, then the next word and thats all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, you may be making things more difficult than they need to be. The comment wasn't meant to pick on you, but whatever compiler/IDE you are using should have been spitting out ERRORS right and left. The fact that it compiled at all is surprising. The advise in the comment was sound. Always, *always* compile with warnings enabled and fix all warnings before you consider your code trustworthy.

That being said, you have a couple of areas where you are making things hard on yourself. You should pass the array, and a `FILE*` pointer (or filename) rather than hardcoding a filename in a function. That makes the function of very limited use. Your use of `fgets`, as you now know, was not correct. Further, after you pass your array, you need only read each word (assuming 1-per line) into the array while making sure your don't exceed the number of rows you have declared.

Here is a short example that will read from the filename given on the command line (or from `stdin` by default). It makes use of a `ternary` operator to either accept a filename as the first argument or set `fp` to `stdin`. Give it a try and let me know if you have questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXW 64  /* maximum number of lines to read */
#define MAXC 32  /* longest word in abridged Dict. is 28 char
                    "Antidisestablishmentarianism"  */

size_t getwords (char (*words)[MAXC], FILE *fp);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char words [MAXW][MAXC] = {{0}};    /* array to hold words  */
    size_t nwords = 0;                  /* number of words read */
    size_t i;

    /* open argv[1] for reading (default: stdin) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    nwords = getwords (words, fp);

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file */

    printf ("\n words read from '%s':\n\n",
            argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdin");
    for (i = 0; i < nwords; i++)
        printf ("  words[%2zu] : %s", i, words[i]);

    return 0;
}

/* function to read words, 1 - per line, from 'fp' */
size_t getwords (char (*words)[MAXC], FILE *fp)
{
    size_t idx = 0;                     /* index of words read */

    /* read each line in file into words array
       note: includes trailing newline character */
    while (idx < MAXW && fgets (words[idx], MAXC, fp)) {
        idx++;
        /* note you should check if chars remain in line */
    }

    if (idx == MAXW)   /* check word count against MAXW */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXW words read.\n");

    return idx;
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o bin/fgets_array_words_fn fgets_array_words_fn.c
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack1.txt
This
is
a
tale
Of
Captain
Jack
Sparrow
A
Pirate
So
Brave
On
the
Seven
Seas.
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_array_words_fn dat/captnjack1.txt

 words read from 'dat/captnjack1.txt':

  words[ 0] : This
  words[ 1] : is
  words[ 2] : a
  words[ 3] : tale
  words[ 4] : Of
  words[ 5] : Captain
  words[ 6] : Jack
  words[ 7] : Sparrow
  words[ 8] : A
  words[ 9] : Pirate
  words[10] : So
  words[11] : Brave
  words[12] : On
  words[13] : the
  words[14] : Seven
  words[15] : Seas.
```

or reading from `stdin`:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_array_words_fn <dat/captnjack1.txt

 words read from 'stdin':

  words[ 0] : This
  words[ 1] : is
  ...
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Also note when passing a 2D array to a function you either pass it as, e.g. `myfunction (char array[][width], ...)` or `myfunction (char (*array)[width], ...)`, but regardless, you must always declare the *width* as part of the function parameter. Then, in the body of your code, you simply call the function using the array name, e.g. `myfunction (array, ...)`. Just know the reason is due to conversion of the first level of indirection to a pointer when passed as a parameter (that explanation is for another day)

Comment: Yes I spent all day at the library trying to figure out why my 2d array was messing up, finally figured it out after like 4 hours that I needed the width in the function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use fread() method

```
while(fread(newWord, MAXWORDLENGTH,1,file)){
    printf("newWord: %s", newWord);
    strcpy(words[i], newWord);
}
```

Comment: Seems to have made my problem worse