# want each word in file to list in array

Tags: c, arrays, file

im a bit stuck here and not sure how to approach this. I have a list of words in a .txt file

example:

```
apple
orange
peach
pear
berry
```

i would like my c program to be able to read the file, and put each word into a array address so i can access each word and analyze it when needed.

for example:

```
apple  ->    array[0]
orange  ->   array[1]
peach  ->    array[2]
pear  ->     array[3]
berry  ->    array[4]
```

All help is appreciated.
Here is what i have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 150

int main()
{
FILE * fpointer;
fpointer = fopen("input.txt", "r");
char singleline[MAX];
char list[MAX];
int i;

while ( !feof(fpointer))
{
    printf("File read\n");

    for ( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++ )
    {
        fgets(singleline, MAX, fpointer);
        printf("%s", fpointer);
        strcpy(list[i], singleline);
    }
}

fclose(fpointer);
return 0;
}
```

The warnings i receive are:

```
filetest.c: In function ‘main’:
filetest.c:22:13: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, 
but 
argument 2 has type ‘FILE * {aka struct __sFILE64 *}’ [-Wformat=]
printf("%s", fpointer);
        ~^
filetest.c:23:11: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from 
integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
strcpy(list[i], singleline);
       ^~~~
In file included from filetest.c:3:0:
/usr/include/string.h:38:8: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is 
of 
type ‘char’
char  *strcpy (char *__restrict, const char *__restrict);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149140/how-to-read-words-from-a-text-file-and-add-to-an-array-of-strings

Comment: And what happens if you try to build and run that code? What is your question?

Comment: sorry i should of posted the warnings. Here they are

Comment: You need to read a good C textbook/tutorial, to learn how to work with files and arrays. `char list[150] = fgets(fpointer, 150, );` is total nonsense.

Comment: well this is exactly why i am asking, i am a first year student and just started learning about these functions this past week

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read words from a text file and add to an array of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149140/how-to-read-words-from-a-text-file-and-add-to-an-array-of-strings)

Comment: thank you for the links, everyone, i have made an update to my code above and updated the errors i am receiving, thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0):

A quick lesson on reading compiler errors and warnings may help you write code that compiles.

> `filetest.c: In function ‘main’:
>   filetest.c:10:25: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ from incompatible 
>   pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>   char list[150] = fgets(fpointer);
>                        ^~~~~~~~
>   In file included from filetest.c:1:0:
>   /usr/include/stdio.h:213:9: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is 
>   of 
>   type ‘FILE * {aka struct __sFILE64 *}’
>   char *  fgets (char *__restrict, int, FILE *__restrict);`

`filetest.c:10:25` is the file, line and column where the error/warning is.  Any decent editor should let you jump right there.  But the compiler helpfully highlights it for you.

```
char list[150] = fgets(fpointer);
                       ^~~~~~~~
```

What's wrong?  The compiler tells you that too: `note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘FILE*‘ ...`, and helpfully shows you the correct prototype for the function: `char *  fgets (char *__restrict, int, FILE *__restrict);`.

So you have passed a `FILE*` where the compiler wanted a `char*`.  And you've only passed one argument where the function expects 2. (
Which is what the next error also says).

---

You've edited the question to fix the error I pointed out, but you just need to keep doing the same thing:
`format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’,  but argument 2 has type ‘FILE *` means you passed a `FILE*` where the function wants a `char*`.

`passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer` means you passed an integer where the function wants a pointer.   And so on...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it. Works how i need it, thank you everyone for the tips.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 150
#define MAXCHAR 20

int main()
{
FILE * fpointer;
fpointer = fopen("input.txt", "r");
char singleline[MAX];
char list[MAX][MAXCHAR];
int i;

while ( !feof(fpointer))
{
    printf("File read\n");

    for ( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++ )
    {
        fgets(singleline, MAXCHAR , fpointer);
        strcpy(list[i], singleline);
    }
}

fclose(fpointer);

for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
{
    if ( strcmp ( list[i] , "STOP" ) == 0 )
    {
        break;
    }
    printf("%s", list[i]); 
}

    return 0;
}
```