# Copying words from a text file into a 2D array of cstrings - C language

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

Basically I have a text file with a bunch of words separated by spaces. My goal is to copy the words into a 2D array of C-strings. What I've done is scan in a line in the file into a C-string, use `strtok` to separate each word of the line by the spaces, and use `strcpy` to copy the words into the 2D array. I also have a counter too keep track of the row of the array that iterates every time I copy a word. How would I go about actually doing the copying?
What I was thinking is doing something like this:

```
token = strtok(NULL, " ");

strcpy(Array2D[counter], token);
```

What I'm doing here is copying the token into the column-cstring that lives at the row counter. Is this something that will work in C? Pretty new to C as a language and just started learning about arrays so my knowledge is limited.

Comment: Did you try it? It's hard to answer here unless you have a more specific question.

Comment: 2D array of strings or 2D array of *characters*. But yes, stuff will work. But more importantly you can [*find the answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149140/how-to-read-words-from-a-text-file-and-add-to-an-array-of-strings) on Stack Overflow if you Google with correct keywords + add `site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Isn't it actually a 1-dimensional array of strings rather than a _2D_?